Fetch not sending cookies across domains with NextJS
I have an app with a NextJS (app router) frontend and ExpressJS backend. I'm using express sessions for authentication. The issue I'm facing is that when I check authentication status from a frontend SSR component, the session cookie is not being properly attached.
This is the function that checks auth on the server side component before then rendering the page:
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

const getSession = async () => {
    const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:80' : 'https://backend.com'

    const url = `${baseURL}/auth/authenticated`

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Cookie: cookies().toString()
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        })

        if (!response.ok) {
            return { authenticated: false } 
        }

        return { authenticated: true}
    } catch (error) {
        return { authenticated: false }
    }
}

Used like this:
export default async function Profile() {
    const { authenticated } = await getSession()

    if(!authenticated) {
        redirect('/')
    } else {
        return (
            <section className="w-full">
                    <ProfilePage />
            </section>
        )
    }
}

The Express sessions setup and CORS looks like so:
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'https://frontend.vercel.app' : 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))
app.use(session({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'none' : 'strict',
        httpOnly: true,
        domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'frontend.vercel.app' : 'localhost' 

     }
}))

This is the cookie being sent from a client component in production:
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    partitioned: null,
    priority: null,
    secure: true,
    domain: frontend.vercel.app,
    sameSite: 'none'
  },
  user: { id: new ObjectId('662ff092323d26bb5abd51c4') }
}

And this is the cookie being sent from a server component:
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
  }
} 

I'm not sure what is going on here, but cookies are definitely a weak area, so any help is appreciated. Let me know if any other code is needed etc.

Turns out this was a basic feature of cookies. As stated in this Reddit post about cookies "Cookies set on [domain a] cannot be accessed by [domain b]". So when I set the cookie's domain to the frontend it meant the backend could no longer access it. A solution is to use a single domain and separate the frontend and backend onto subdomains.
